# Dagitty Adjustment Sets in R

Tags: r

I have the following code from `dagitty`:

```
library(dagitty)
g1 <- dagitty( "dag {
    W1 -> Z1 -> X -> Y
    Z1 <- V -> Z2
    W2 -> Z2 -> Y
    X <-> W1 <-> W2 <-> Y
}")

adjustmentSets(g1, 'Z1', 'X')
# { W1 }
```

I want to get the output of the `adjustmentSets()`function (W1) to output a formula.

Basically the third argument of the `adjustmentSets()` function is the outcome and the second argument is one of the regressors. The additional regressors are based on what comes out of `adjustmentSets()`. Sometimes there can be multiple adjustment sets, but I only need to grab one of them it doesn't matter which one.

In this example the expected output is `X ~ Z1 + W1`.

If the output of `adjustmentSets()` was { W1, W2}. the expected output would be `X ~ Z1 + W1 + W2`.

If the output of `adjustmentSets()` was `{W1 W2} {Z2 Z1}`. We would only grab one set, so a correct output would be `X ~ Z1 + W1 + W2` or `X ~ Z1 + Z1 + Z2`.

Answer (score 0):

The output is a `list` of length 1.

```
> adjustmentSets(g1, 'Z1', 'X') %>% str
List of 1
 $ 1: chr "W1"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "dagitty.sets"
```

So, we can use standard extractors (`[[` or `$`) to get the value

```
adjustmentSets(g1, 'Z1', 'X')[[1]]
[1] "W1"
```

If we need a formula, then use `reformulate` to construct one

```
reformulate(c("Z1", adjustmentSets(g1, 'Z1', 'X')[[1]]), response = "X")
X ~ Z1 + W1
```

Note that `adjustmentSets` doesn't return the other input 'Z1' or 'X'